# Use status bar on the iOS for phonegap

Tags: ios, notifications, statusbar, phonegap-plugins

How I can use Status bar on iOS for phonegap to send notification?
On android is the plugin: [StatusBarNotification](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the LocalNotification plugin will do what you're after:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/LocalNotifications

And a more detailed tutorial:

http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=117